# Sum of char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a little trouble of calculating sum of elements in char array. I tried like this but it does not give what I expect:

```
int count1=0;
    char [] charArray1={1,2,35,0};
    for (int i =0; i<charArray.length; i++){

        count1=count1+charArray1[i];

    }
```

I'm getting Exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 105
    at CountDigits.main(CountDigits.java:31)

Any hint please?

Comment: are you trying to calculate the sum of numbers in the array?

Comment: You do know that `'i'` is a *character literal*? It can't be used as an array index. I think you need to go back to the basics again.

Comment: Will I loose the accuracy if I convert the char array to int array? Or it is bad idea?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate the elements in the char array.

Comment: If this `for (int i =0; i<charArray.length; i++)` not meant to use `charArray1.length`?

Comment: Are you not maybe confusing `char` for `byte` because you are using the numerical value of the char and never the character value?

Comment: If you are just looking for a small number, `char` is not the correct thing to use, `byte` is. If you have to print `char c = (char) 0;` you will not get an output because 0 on the Ascii table is not a visible character. Therefore I am not sure why you are storing those numbers in a `char[]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89242/discussion-between-user1364513-and-nicholas-robinson).

Comment: @user1364513 I can't get back to the chat room, this type of question is designed **not to** use array. You should get the digit one by one from the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

In the **first** place, you should be using an `int` array instead of `char` array if your data is purely numberic.

```
int[] data = {1,2,35,0};
```

**Secondly**, your addition in the iteration is incorrect.

```
int sum;
for(int x=0; x<data.length ;x++)
    sum += data[x];    //This is enough to get the sum.
```

---

At the moment, I cannot think of any good reason to use char array to store an array of numbers. But if you have to do it for some mysterious reasons, you can do it this way.

```
char[] data = {'1', '2', '3', '0'};  //Enclose each char with single quote
int sum;
for(int x=0; x<data.length ;x++)
    sum += Character.getNumericValue(data[x]);    //Convert char to int before summing
```

Comment: but what can you if I want to identify each character, then calculate the sum? so it means int does not do it!

Comment: @user1364513 If you **have** to use char array for some reasons, you have to convert each of them to `int` first before summing up.

Comment: Then what do you  think about the accuracy? If I convert from char to int? Will not loose anything?

Comment: char in java is 16bit while int is 32bit. You shouldn't loose percision.
`int x = Character.getNumericValue(char)`

Comment: @user1364513 Unless you are using a different encoding, there might be (needs confirmation). But usually you won't lose anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the for loop as follows where I have change the `charArray` to `charArray1` and line in for loop

```
 for (int i =0; i<charArray1.length; i++){
        count1=count1+charArray1[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count1=charArray1['i']+charArray1['i']; is wrong.
```

what you need is

```
count1 = count1 + charArray1[i];
```

Comment: Yes, but it's more useful to say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good answere are self-explaining :) although apprantently mine is not

Comment: @gefei: If you have a side-by-side diff, yes... otherwise often not

Answer (score 0):

Change this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
    count1 = charArray1['i'] + charArray1['i'];
}
```

to this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
    count1 = count1 + charArray1[i];
}
```

In Java, we cannot use a character or string literal for indexing an array. Only numbers are allowed. Since `i` is an integer, you need to use it directly as the index.

As T. J. Crowder pointed out in the comment - in order to get the sum of all the numbers, you need what is called an `accumulator` into which you will collect the result of the sum. In every loop iteration, you need to add the next element to this accumulator result so that in the end, it will hold the result of -

```
charArray1[0] + charArray1[1] + charArray1[2] + charArray1[3]
```

Comment: You might want to mention the second change you made (and why).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    public int add(char[] numbers) {
    int result = 0;
    for (char i : numbers) {
        if(Character.isDigit(i)){
            result += Character.getNumericValue(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer, but nevertheless, change your code to something below -

```
 int count1 = 0;
 char [] charArray1 = {1,2,35,0};
 for (int i =0; I < charArray1.length; i++)
 {
 count1 = count1 + charArray1[i];
 }
  
 System.out.println("sum is " + count1);
```

This code can further be optimized, but if you simply want to fix the error, then try below.